# eliminar información de BD sqlite sin afectar el consecutivo de la variable PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

como puedo hacer que al eliminar información de una base de datos sqlite la variable primary key autoincrement enumere nuevamente la información que quede dentro de la base de datos, para que de esta manera los id no queden salteados si no que queden otra vez enumerados de forma consecutiva.

````
    public static final String ID_ASIGNATURA="id_asignatura";
    public static final String CAMPO_NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA="nombre_asignatura";

    public static final String CREAR_TABLA_ASIGNATURAS="CREATE TABLE " +""
            +TABLA_ASIGNATURAS+" ("+ID_ASIGNATURA+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CAMPO_NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA+ " TEXT)"; ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Automáticamente no se puede. El contador sigue incrementándose siempre y cada nueva fila que agregues va a tener un número nuevo mayor que el anterior, no importa si has borrado otra filas anteriores y te quedaron huecos.

Podrías escribir un proceso en Java que renumere todas las claves primarias, pero realmente me cuesta pensar un caso donde esto sea necesario, además de la complejidad porque seguramente la clave primaria esa será una clave foránea en otras tablas, y si lo cambias en una tienes que cambiarlas en todas, porque si no los datos perderán la consistencia.

En realidad la clave primaria es para identificar unívocamente una fila en la BD, y poder relacionarla con otras tablas, y debería ser un dato interno que nunca se muestra al usuario, por lo tanto no importa si es consecutivo o no. El hecho que quieras que sea siempre consecutiva me hace pensar que es un dato que estás utilizando para otra cosa, lo mejor sería que es dato que representa algo más que un identificador de fila, lo agregues como otra columna, donde podrás manejarlo a tu antojo sin problemas de consistencia o depender del autoincrement de la BD.